# line 1 this command fin angular

Tags: angular, bash, variables, path

I'm trying to install angular but my bash terminal cannot find my angular version. I think that my problem comes from my system variables but even when I rearrange the paths, it doesn't work.

Here's what my terminal is returning when I try the `ng --version` command line :

```
C:\Users\tonyl\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

As you can see, my path is not good at all. It starts with \ and ends with normal /.

I would really appreciate to have someone who have a solution for this.

thank you guys !

Comment: The message tell you that `This` is not a command!

Comment: Did you open the cmd as administrator to globally install angular/cli?

Comment: HI ! I installed angular/cli via the bash terminal in visual studio code. Also, I can find the repository of angular cli in my npm repository

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete your npm and npm-cache folder and try to reinstall it globally

Comment: Yes, indeed. And it didn't work at all. Also, my ng --version is foundable via my global windows CMD. It's only on VScode that it doesn't work